# Why jsf <h:inputHidden../> is taking space on the screen?

Tags: html, css, jsf-2

Among most primefaces component on my screen, I happen to have used an `h:inputHidden` on my xhtml page as I needed a hidden field to store/update a bean field value.

```
<h:inputHidden id="calendarValueHidden" value="#{myCdiBean.calValue}"/>
```

Even though it is not visible, but I don't know why it is taking space on the screen which has disturbed other components of the page. Even `display:none !important` is not working on the input hidden component.

Comment: This is not the default behavior and the cause of the problem is not visible in the information posted so far. Please, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  As of now I can only make an educated guess it being caused by one of most common starter's mistake: placing it in a panel grid (at least, just looking in the generated HTML output should give clues).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem symptoms indicate a common starter's mistake: declaring it as an immediate child of a `<h:panelGrid>`. Like so:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:inputHidden ... />
    <h:inputText ... />
</h:panelGrid>
```

The `<h:panelGrid>` generates a HTML `<table>` and, [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/panelGrid.html), it will put **every direct child** in its own table cell `<td>`. The generated HTML output looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="hidden" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

A `<td>` has by default some margin and padding which totally explains your problem. You should have noticed it when inspecting the HTML output and CSS styles in browser's builtin developer toolset (press F12 or rightclick, *Inspect Element*).

You basically want to group the `<h:inputHidden>` along with the desired `<h:inputText>` inside the same table cell. You can use `<h:panelGroup>` for that.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:inputText ... />
        <h:inputHidden ... />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText ... />
</h:panelGrid>
```

This will end up in the generated HTML output as below, exactly as you intented:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" /><input type="hidden" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using tables for layout and positioning is bad. Use divs and CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I really didn't know this about the panel grids. Thanks for taking out time for the thorough explanation.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, I placed the hidden field inside the panel grid, just after the component, the value of which it holds. I took it out of the panel grid and placed it in the end just before the end of the `form` tag. Problem solved.

Looks like a panel grid does not take a hidden field for actually a literally non-present component. It is still counted by a panel grid because it is still in dom. For an element to be an uncountable element in panel grid, it has to be unrendered (`rendered="false"`). But then it also becomes totally inaccessible and its value wont be available as it is no more in dom.

Comment: No. You're not properly understanding the problem and unnecessarily blaming JSF instead of your own ignorance about basic HTML. Once again, look in generated HTML output for the why. You basically told JSF to put the `<input type="hidden">` in its own `<td>` element of a `<table>`. Why is that JSF's mistake? What should it have done otherwise? Why are you not telling JSF to group the hidden input with the other component in the same `<td>`?